# angular-tree-component undefined path error

Tags: angular, typescript, jstree

I tried to get a full path from my angular-tree-component. But unfortunately I always have an undefined at the end of my Array. I think this happens when the while loop trys to push a parent when there is no more parent. 
Thanks for your help!

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J03KE.png)

```
path: String[] = [];
options: ITreeOptions = {
 actionMapping: {
   mouse: {
     dblClick: (tree, node, $event) => {
      let parent = node.parent;
      while(parent !== null){
      this.path.push(parent.data.name);
      parent = parent.parent;
      console.log(this.path);
     }
      this.getFilePath();
    }
   }
 }
}

getFilePath(){
this.path.reverse();
  for(let p of this.path){
      this.filePath += p + "/";
  }
  this.filePath = "";
  this.path = [];
}
```

Comment: use: `while(parent.parent !== null)` ?

Comment: instead of `public filePath: string;` u need to initialize it with `public filePath: string = ''`

Comment: Please format your code properly, it's a bit confusing to read.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. Looks like a general question about implementing an algorithm. Debug it to see why the `undefined` is added into the array.